# Webdriver IO Setup behind the cooperate Proxy

Tags: webdriver-io

I did install WebDriver IO v7.11. But when  I tried to configure

```
npx wdio config
```

get the following error.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path c:\<folder>\node_modules\chromedriver
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm ERR! Current existing ChromeDriver binary is unavailable, proceeding with download and extraction.
npm ERR! Downloading from file:  https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/92.0.4515.107/chromedriver_win32.zip
npm ERR! Saving to file: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\1\92.0.4515.107\chromedriver\chromedriver_win32.zip
npm ERR! Using workaround for https-url combined with a proxy.
npm ERR! ChromeDriver installation failed Error: Error with http(s) request: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
npm ERR!     at requestBinary (c:\<folder>\node_modules\chromedriver\install.js:265:11)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
npm ERR!     at async downloadFile (c:\<folder>\node_modules\chromedriver\install.js:109:5)
```

Works fine outside the cooperate proxy. Any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. I hope this might help for others.

I set an env variable

```
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

and run again. Worked.